# How to remove all instances of a character from a list of strings?

Tags: python

I have a list of tweets and I have to count the instances of each word and turn that into a dictionary. But I also have to remove certain characters, ignore the newline ('\n') character, and make all characters uppercase.

This is my code but somehow some of the characters that I want to remove are still in the output. I don't know if I missed something here.

Note: "tweet_texts" is the name of the list of tweets.

```
words_dict = {} #where I store the words
remove_chars = "&$@[].,'#()-\"!?’_" #characters to be removed

tweet_texts = [t.upper() for t in tweet_texts]
tweet_texts = [t.replace('\n','') for t in tweet_texts]

for chars in remove_chars:
    tweet_texts = [t.replace(chars,'') for t in tweet_texts]
        
for texts in tweet_texts:
    
    words = texts.split()
    
    for word in words:
        if word in words_dict:
            words_dict[word] += 1
        else:
            words_dict[word] = 1
        
print(words_dict)

>>> {'RT': 53, '1969ENIGMA:': 1, 'SONA': 60,“WALANG': 1, 'SUSTANSYA”:': 1} #this isn't the whole output, the actual output is really long so I cut it
```

Comment: You can use Counter. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Use `re.sub()` to replace lots of characters in one call, rather than a loop.

Comment: Your sample output doesn't have any of the characters that are supposed to be removed.

Comment: Where would I put the re.sub()?

Comment: `tweet_texts = [re.sub(regex, '', t) for t in tweet_texts]`

Comment: Sorry about that. The sample output isn't complete because it's too long.

Comment: Where `regex` is a regular expression that matches all your remove characters.

Comment: We don't need the complete output, just some examples of a bad character being left in.

Comment: The "WALANG and SUSTANSYA" in the output has a " which I want removed.

Comment: That character isn't in your `remove_chars` string. Notice that it's a curly quote, not a straight quote.

Comment: I thought that was just a copying error, because there's no quote at the beginning.

Comment: Oh but some outputs also didn't get rid of the periods like this 'HIM…': 1, F…': 2

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example output, I can see the character `“`, which looks a lot like `"`, but is not in your list of characters to remove.

```py
print('"' == '“')  # False
print(ord('"'))  # 34
print(ord('“'))  # 8220
```

Perhaps you could try using a regular expression to keep word and whitespace characters only. Like this.

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

clean_tweets = [re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", "", tweet) for tweet in tweet_texts]
words_dict = Counter()

for tweet in clean_tweets:
    words_dict.update(tweet.split())
```